# How to find the number of times a weather station registered a certain temperature?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem is as follows:

> The temperature in the city of Daegu on March 1st, 2020 is given by:
>
> $15+5\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{12}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ in celcius, where
> $t\in [0,24]$. Assume $t$ is the time elapsed in hours from midnight.
> Using this information. Find how many times the temperature of the
> city was measured to be $17.5$ celcius.

What I've attempted to do in order to solve this problem isn't much. What I arrived was this:

$$15+5\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{12}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=17.5$$

Then this is reduced to:

$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{12}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$

But now what? I could use the inverse sine function as:

$$\frac{\pi t}{12}=\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

But from looking at this effort, I don't seem this would help me to get the value of $t$, needless to say. Assuming that I could get that value. **How can I get how many times that temperature was attained?**. Therefore I need assistance in this problem.

Comment: Note that $\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{12}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{2.5}5=\frac{1}{2}$ not $\frac14$.

Comment: Revise how you, in general, solve the equations of the type $\sin x=a$ (where $a\in[-1,1]$). For example, draw the graph of the sine function and the line $y=a$ and see where they intersect. Try to understand how the set of intersection points is related to $\sin^{-1}(a)$. Then apply that knowledge to $x=\frac{\pi t}{12}+\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $a=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Soheil Sorry about that, yes I corrected the error

Comment: @StinkingBishop Sorry. I'm not very savvy with this concept. So I am doing what you mentioned from my precalculus textbook. I have the idea. The reason why I got stuck is that the trigonometric inverse function of $\frac{1}{4}$ isn't known. Or at least I don't know how to get it. But it turns out that is $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{6}$. Now what?

Comment: Really I would now refer you to the answer you already have below. I don't think I can add anything/do anything better than @SiongThyeGoh has done for you...

Answer (score 3):

from $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{12} + \frac{\pi} 2\right)=\frac12$$

We have $$\frac{\pi t}{12} + \frac{\pi}2 = k\pi + (-1)^k\cdot \frac{\pi}6, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Simplifying, we have
$$t + 6 = 12k + 2(-1)^k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$t  = 12k - 6 + 2(-1)^k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Now, we have the restriction of $t$ should be in $[0, 24]$.

When $k=0,$ we have $t<0$

When $k=1$, we have $t=12-6-2=4.$

When $k=2$, we have $t=24-6+2=20$

When $k=3$, we have $t = 36-6-2 > 24$.

Hence the answer is two times.

Answer (score 1):

First note that
$$15+5\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{12}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=17.5$$
$$5\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{12}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac52$$
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{12}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac12$$
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{12}\right)=\frac12$$
Which yields
$$\frac{\pi t_1}{12}=\frac\pi3+2\pi k,\ \mbox{for}\ k\in\mathbb Z$$
$$\frac{\pi t_2}{12}=\frac{5\pi}{3}+2\pi k,\ \mbox{for}\ k\in\mathbb Z$$
Solving for $t_1$ and $t_2$, we have
$$t_1=24k+4,\ \mbox{for}\ k\in\mathbb Z$$
$$t_2=24k+20,\ \mbox{for}\ k\in\mathbb Z$$
The only scenario in which $t_i\in[0, 24]$ is when $k=0$. So now we have
$$0\le t_1=4\le 24$$
$$0\le t_2=20\le 24$$
Therefore on March 1st, 2020, there were two occurrences in which the city of Daegu attained a temperature of $17.5^\circ \mathrm C$.